# SQL Runner (Google Looker) change date format in query

Tags: sql, datetime, runner, looker

This topic has been covered several times but I can't find a solution that applies to SQL Runner, which is the custom query portion of Google's Looker platform.

I am attempting to reformat a `datetime` SELECT statement from yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy.

Currently what I have is:

```
SELECT 
CAST(shift.datetime AS DATE)
FROM table.a
```

This gives me the yyyy-mm-dd result but so far my efforts to CONVERT have been fruitless. It does not appear that SQL Runner supports the CONVERT command or I am utilizing it incorrectly.

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: SQL Runner is just running SQL queries on your database. What database is it connecting to?

Comment: @SimonD, it is connected to Snowflake. Maybe I should flip through their documentation to see supported commands and queries then?

Comment: Yeah that's right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe sql runner is just gives us a way to directly access the db and it will not change any sql query while communicating with the db directly as long as the timezone of both explore as well as db matches.

**Maybe something like this should work for your case**

https://sql.tutorialink.com/convert-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-snowflake/

lmk if the above works for your or not!

Comment: please post the answer and details about the answer, not external links

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31679047)